# JavaScript mouseover/mouseleave causing flickering on some browsers (IE & FF)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, web

I'm having trouble with a site I'm designing. Unfortunately I've fallen into the trap of not designing it for Internet Explorer first, but stuck to a friendlier browser such as Chrome. Now that I look at a it in IE, I've found a problem that I'm a bit dumbfounded by.

The menu links here-

http://mydomain.com/apassociates/page/home

...flicker and collapse. If you want to see how it's supposed to look please check it out in Chrome.

I'm not a professional web developer and I suspect that these problems could be elementary to the more experienced developer, but I'm not actually sure where to begin.

Does anyone have any thoughts or pointers for either of this problem?

---

So to try an help focus this as per the advice from the comments, here's the HTML-

```
<div id='home-pictures'>

    <a href='http://mydomain.com/apassociates/page/conservatory'>
        <div id='home-1'>
            <span class='home-link'>Traditional</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href='http://mydomain.com/apassociates/page/blackbrookhouse'>
        <div id='home-2'>
            <span class='home-link'>Commercial</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href='http://mydomain.com/apassociates/page/floodproof'>
        <div id='home-3'>
            <span class='home-link'>Innovative</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The javascript here, works to replace the background image upon mouseover-

```
// home links
$('div#home-1').mouseover(function () {
  $('div#home-1').css('background-image', 'url(/apassociates/images/content/devonhouse-caption-wash.png)');
});

$('div#home-1').mouseleave(function () {
  $('div#home-1').css('background-image', 'url(/apassociates/images/content/devonhouse-caption.png)');
});
```

I've only included the code for the first link, the other code is just a duplication of these with different identity tags.

I'm left wondering whether I would do better to put each link into its own div of fixed dimension. Might that prevent the collapsing/flickering?

Comment: Could give this a shot - add this META tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge,chrome=1" />`. Not the recommended way to go about it but can often provide a quick-fix.

Comment: giving this a go now, thanks!

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Do this for each of your differetn questions.  Post this code into the question, or in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: The portfolio is flickering on Firefox 17.0.1 for Mac too. I think the problem here is javascript related, but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: Wallace- I think it must be javascript yes.

KatieK- would you recommend posting the whole source code for each page separately, or just the javascript that is likely to be the problem?

Comment: http://mikloswe.nextmp.net/apassociates/assets/js/hover.js this js is full of mouseover & mouseleave. The image background changes on both of them, maybe you should try to decide what you actually want to get done and do whatever you're trying to do in some other way...

Comment: The intention is to make the image have a glossy white effect upon mouseover. It looks good in browsers where it works such as chrome.

Comment: Firefox 17 is the latest FF version. If it doesn't work on a major browser you have a problem... I'm trying to work it out, but won't promise anything. As KatieK said, you better isolate the problem to make it easier to help you out. :)

Comment: Thanks Wallace, I appreciate any help you can give. In terms of isolating the problem, I am convince it's the javascript, like you said. Would it help to post that code?

Comment: The background image on your page is 2.6mb. Just sayin'.

Comment: Thanks Billy, I will reduce that before I make it live :)

Comment: Your carousel_image spans which are within the 'a' tags are set as 'block' level elements. You shouldn't have block level elements with 'a' tags. Older IE versions may grumble about that.

Comment: You should really [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmikloswe.nextmp.net%2Fapassociates%2Fpage%2Fhome&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) _before_ doing anything else.  Explorer tends to hate invalid HTML.

Comment: StackOverflow is not really about these _"I don't know what I'm doing so please fix this list of issues on my entire website"_ type questions.  Please make each new post a single concise question along with relevant code.

Comment: I also think you should divide the two issues on this question into two specific questions, otherwise you'll risk loosing reputation really fast with down-votes! I recommend you keep this question for the flickering javascript problem and create another question for the grid/column problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to isolate your problem and resolve it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamyguy/zWwdH/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="home-pictures">
    <a href="http://mikloswe.nextmp.net/apassociates/page/conservatory">
        <div id="home-1" style="background-image: url(http://mikloswe.nextmp.net/apassociates/images/content/devonhouse-caption.png);">
            <span class="home-link">Traditional</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://mikloswe.nextmp.net/apassociates/page/blackbrookhouse">
        <div id="home-2" style="background-image: url(http://mikloswe.nextmp.net/apassociates/images/content/carehome-caption.png);">
            <span class="home-link">Commercial</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://mikloswe.nextmp.net/apassociates/page/floodproof">
        <div id="home-3" style="background-image: url(http://mikloswe.nextmp.net/apassociates/images/content/submersible-caption.png);">
            <span class="home-link">Innovative</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#home-pictures {
    height: 250px;
}
#home-pictures {
    text-align: center;
}
#home-pictures a:link,
#home-pictures a:visited {
    color: #B43104;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#home-1, #home-2, #home-3 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    height: 256px;
    width: 285px;
    zoom: 1;
}
.home-link {
    color: #B43104;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'book antiqua', palatino, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: 220px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// home links
$('div#home-1, div#home-2, div#home-3').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=50)',
        'opacity' : '0.5'
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
  $(this).css({
        'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=100)',
        'opacity' : '1.0'
    });
});
```

I changed the javascript so that it doesn't rely on images for the hover, but on opacity. That will affect the font below the image since it's also within the div, but maybe you could have a dedicated div within each one of these (like 'div.image') and set the background & opacity to only the image and not the whole item...

UPDATE:

Opacity can be tricky on IE. Updated the css and javascript so that it works on IE too... The fiddle was updated as well. Cross-browser opacity was taken from [this post](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/), which I keep coming back to...

Comment: Thanks Wallace, opactiy would seem to be the way to go, maybe I just need to simplify this whole part. I tried to implement what you've posted, but it doesn't seem to have done the trick. I suspect I missed something though. Cheers for your help!

Comment: Note that I only made the url to the image absolute to be able to work on the fiddle. You don't have to do that locally. You can still go the image way if you want, but I think the opacity one demands less overhead. In this case, `mouseenter` combined with `mouseleave` will give more reliable results. The function can be significantly simplified, as you can see. Going to bed now, let me know how it went once you have tested it. ;)

Comment: Updated the code with support for opacity on Internet Explorer 5-9.

Comment: I managed to solve this. I opacity as you said, but I noticed that I'd left some styles linked to a:hover that was interfering with the Javascript, removing it helped a lot. I also found this tutorial very helpful- shopdev.co.uk/blog/animated-menus-using-jquery/ thanks again for your help.